# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: mysql

First of all i'm newbie in coding. I try to " insert if no exists else update" my database. I use code below:

```
$query = "     
          INSERT INTO offers ( user_i , startPoli_i , finalPoli_i ,depDay_i , onoma_pro , epitheto_pro , prosfora , comments_pro ,string_uniq) 
       VALUES ( :u1 , :sP1, :fP1 ,:dD1, :op, :ep , :p , :cp , :su) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      string_uniq = :su
       "; 


    $query_params = array(
        ':u1' => $_POST['user_i'],
        ':sP1' => $_POST['startPoli_i'],
         ':fP1' => $_POST['finalPoli_i'],
        ':dD1' => $_POST['depDay_i'],
        ':op' => $_POST['onoma_pro'],
        ':ep' => $_POST['epitheto_pro'],
        ':p' => $_POST['prosfora'],
        ':cp' => $_POST['comments_pro'],
        ':su' => $_POST['string_unique']
    );
```

I declare 'string_uniq' column as unique. My table uses `MyISAM`. The problem: when `":su"` value is identical to an existent value of `column 'string_uniq'` and for `example ":p"` value is different, no update takes place. Any suggestion; Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add the fields you want updated like:

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      string_uniq = :su, prosfora = :p
```